# Bootstrap 3 - How to change the hyperlink title text showing as tooltip using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the hyperlink title using javascript/jquery when the link is clicked. 
HTML

```
<a 
        href="javascript:addRss('234');" 
        class="btn btn-success" 
        title="Add content to Personal RSS" 
        id="addRssbtn" 
        data-toggle="tooltip" >
            <i class="fa fa-rss fa-lg"></i> 
        </a>
```

CSS

```
@import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.1.1/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css");
@import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css");
@import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css");
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function (){$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({});});


function addRss(hash){
        $("#addRssbtn").attr("class", "btn btn-success active");
        $("#addRssbtn").attr("title", "Remove content from Personal RSS");
        $("#addRssbtn").attr("href", "javascript:unaddRss(" + hash + ");");

//some other post data stuff
};
```

the title gets changed and shows too, only if i am not using

```
data-toggle="tooltip"
```

so how can i make the data-toggle="tooltip" to show the new changed title as a tooltip when the link is clicked ?

http://jsfiddle.net/h5kKa/

above code is working except the new tooltip on my pc but not on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update the tooltip using the `fixTitle` option.

```
$("#addRssbtn").attr("title", "Remove content from Personal RSS")
```

Becomes

```
$("#addRssbtn").attr("title", "Remove content from Personal RSS").tooltip('fixTitle');
```

You can add `.tooltip('show');` to show the tooltip straight after:

```
$("#addRssbtn").attr("title", "Remove content from Personal RSS").tooltip('fixTitle').tooltip('show');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h5kKa/2/

Answer (score 1):

You weren't looking for anything like this this were you?

```
$("#addRssbtn").tooltip("option", "content", "title");
```

[Here is a jfiddle for it](http://jsfiddle.net/h5kKa/9/)

E: just beaten